# FB.login redirect_uri

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use Fb.Login for logging in user in my facebook application. Does exist the posibilities for a redirect_uri parameter? After the succesufull login i would like to redirect user to: https://www.facebook.com/page/app_33229693355?app_data=code, on classic login I user redirect_uri parameter to redirect after login, but here?

```
FB.login(function(response) {
}, {scope: \'publish_stream, photo_upload, user_birthday\'});
```

I need this because the next step is to write a picture in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
      window.location = "http://example.com";
  });
```

Redirect will be fired when the auth status changes to connected. Checkout this [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) Link for more info.

If you want users data,

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
         // make an ajax call to your php code and pass the name etc ...
         // on success of the ajax call, use window.location to redirect 
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```

Comment: It seems that I loose $facebook->getUser(); , returns null, but how can I get it back? I found something like this

       FB.Event.subscribe(\'auth.login\', function(response) {
        window.location = \'http://ingersidemon.ro/proiecte/pitzi-world.ro/.facebook/ziuanasterii/index.php?app_data=ok\';
        alert(response.userID);
       });
but i think i didnt arange the code good

Comment: I am I little new in javascript so how do i get in php the variables?

I tried $name = '<script>response.name</script>'; echo var_export($name, true); ... not working

Comment: So what is the purpose of your fb app? Or what functionality you wanna build ?

Comment: I press the button, it appear Fb.login, it logins, and after i give permisions must access a part of script of same page where it generates a picture and post on his profile.